# how to avoid apscheduler add jobs to subprocess?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I hava added a apscheduler job to my process,, the I find my subprocess also have this job,,
and my main process and subporcesss excute the job at same time...

main program is

```
server = StreamServer((server_ip, server_port), serve_forever, spawn = pool, backlog=100000)

for i in range(process_count - 1):
    Process(target=serve_forever, args=()).start()
```

my apscheduler is

```
   scheduler =BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.start()
```

ouput is

```
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11428
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11431
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11424
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11430
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11426
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11380
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11425
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11429
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11432
Tick! The time is: 1409042763.26 pocess is 11433
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. Start the scheduler only after you've created the subprocesses
2. Shut down the scheduler in the subprocesses
3. Create the subprocesses by some other way than forking the main process

Comment: you are totally right..when i move the scheduler after created the subprocesses,it behave right,,but why is that,,my Process have a target function,Doesn't it will exec the target function other than my main process

Comment: The target function exists in the subprocess too. The scheduler doesn't know whether it's in a subprocess or main process. When you create the subprocess, another copy of the scheduler is created and it behaves the same way as the one in the parent process.